# How do I authenticate through a generic OAuth2 provider in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0

We have an in-house Single Sign On server, built on IdentityServer2 and we use it to authenticate many different web products. Some of these products are in .NET, some in ColdFusion and we are adding another in Ruby on Rails.

I am having a great deal of difficulty, though, in finding information on connecting to any generic OAuth2 provider. All of the information seems to revolve around Omniauth and the specific provider gems that most people connect to. These, however, will not help me.

I just need someone to point me in the right direction. I don't care if it's using Omniauth, Rack or anything else. I just need something that will provide some sort of instructions on how to get this working in Rails.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It looks like the oauth2 gem might be a help, but I can't find any information on how to implement it in rails.

Comment: I am making progress on this and will post a solution once I have it completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a generic way to do this as it all depends on the SSO server setup. I ended up just building the auth string according to what the server was asking for and then using the JWT token to process the token it gave back.

The only thing I can say is that if you run into this issue, either check with the folks managing the SSO server to see what the request URL should contain or check the documentation of the SSO software if you are doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `doorkeeper` gem which is a OAuth 2 provider for Rails and Grape.You can go

https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper

hope that helps you.

Comment: In looking at this product it looked like it was an OAuth2 provider and not a consumer. I already have a provider, which is the SSO server mentioned above. That's what I need to connect my Rails app to. Does doorkeeper also act as a consumer?

Comment: yes doorkeeper acts as a consumer as well.Basically you will have to create an app using doorkeeper then you will get something like **oauth_client_id** and **oauth_client_secret** .
Then you can send request using the value of those key.

Comment: I don't see any documentation on how to implement doorkeeper as a consumer. Can you point me to anything?

Comment: follow this [link](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-provider-app) 
Just do `bundle install`
then the most important `bundle exec rake db:setup`

this command will generate necessary table and data.You can find the app_id and client_secret from your database.

Then follow the wiki [link](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/API-endpoint-descriptions-and-examples)

Comment: Also i encourage you to watch [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/353-oauth-with-doorkeeper) episode by Ryan Bates.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am asking. I don't need to alter the database to authenticate to another server. I have seen the webcast and it is very good to learn how to set up a provider, but I am looking to set up a consumer, which is an entirely different animal.